# SQL error - Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Database'

Tags: sql, sql-server, navision

I want to detect databases beginning with 'NAV'in a MS SQL DB. I tried it with this code:

```
DECLARE @DBName NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @DBName = (SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases where name LIKE '%NAV%');
EXECUTE ('USE' + @DBName);
```

But I got the error message:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Database'.
```

Do know what is wrong there?

Comment: do this... `declare @sql varchar(4000) = ('USE' + @DBName); print(@sql)` and you'll see you need a space at a minimum (assuming that query returns only one result). It's always good to print your dynamic sql before attempting to execute it so you can see what's actually being executed.

Comment: Are you using `sa` to run that query?

Comment: Obligatory link for dynamic SQL questions for SQL Server: http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a space after USE and put brackets around the database name:

```
DECLARE @DBName NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @DBName = (SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases where name LIKE '%NAV%');
EXECUTE ('USE [' + @DBName + ']');
```

Comment: Or use [QUOTENAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about the keyword database in the error message, but I do spot problems:
You concatenate `USE` and the databasename without a space: `USENAV01` doesn't work. You should use `'USE ' + QUOTENAME(@DBName)`.

Secondly, I don't know what the intention is, but if you do `EXECUTE ('USE ' + @DBName);` followed by other (dynamic) queries, the following queries are executed on your *current* connection. In other words, the `USE XXX` doesn't matter for the following queries.

Thirdly, as mentioned by Jesse in below comment; if you have more than one database with a `name like '%NAV%'` (which your question suggests), your code is only executed for one of those databases. Which one that will be is unpredictable without an `order by`. If you want to execute code for all relevant databases, you have to loop through them.

Comment: very good point on the follow on queries. I hope this was a water downed example and the dynamic sql is longer, and deserving of being dynamic.

Comment: In addition to this, If there is more than 1 database like %NAV% this code will break as you can only assign one to a variable.  You'd have to use a temp table and loop through it to be more precise.